# Conditional HOC in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In brief, is it possible to make a conditional HOC (Higher order Component) in ReactJS?

My scenario:

I have these components:

- Modal.jsx,
- WithGATracking.jsx
- GAModal.jsx

Modal is just a normal pop-up component;

WithGATracking is the HOC which does some extra things on top of the Modal component.

Here is the code for **GAModal.jsx**

```
import Modal from './Modal.js';
import WithGATracking from './Hoc/WithGADurationTracking.jsx';

export default WithGATracking ({startEventName:"event-name"})(Modal);
```

this is how we use it:

```
      {
                this.state.showSlider && 
                <GAModal id="photo-popup" title={this.props.Name}>
                    {slider}
                </GAModal>
            }
```

Is it possible to remove the code which controls whether to show or hide the GAModal and put this piece of code inside of GAModal?

**What I have tried:**

```
class GAModal extends Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props && this.props.isOpen) {
            return (
                WithGATracking ({startEventName:"event-name"})(Modal)
            );
        }

        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

export default GAModal;
```

**And here is how I use it after the change:**

```
<GAModal id="photo-popup" title={this.props.Name} isOpen={this.state.showSlider} >
    {slider}
</GAModal>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: GAModal.render(): A valid React
>   element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined,
>   an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: In the cases where `isOpen == false` or undefined you should `return <Modal />;` and not just the class name (assuming `Modal` is a react component class). Also the second code snippet you shared isn't actually returning anything.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the a component inside the GAModal component, instead you need to render it like

```
const GATracking = WithGATracking ({startEventName:"event-name"})(Modal);
class GAModal extends Component { 
    render() {
        if (this.props && this.props.isOpen) { 
            return (
                <GATracking {...this.props} />
            ); 
        }

        else {
            return <Modal {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }
}

export default GAModal;
```

Comment: Syntax Error:     Module build failed: SyntaxError: /src/app/modules/sharedComponents/GAModal.jsx: Unexpected token (7:20)

   5 | class GAModal extends Component {
   6 | 
>  7 |     GAModalTracking = WithGATracking({ startEventName: "event-name" })(Modal);
     | ^

Comment: The syntax error could be because you might not have configured babel to use class fields. anyways the updated answer should work for you

Comment: yep, the update solved the Syntax error, but the Modal doesn't pop up anymore. >_<;

Comment: It should come up if `isOpen` prop is true

Comment: You are right. It now pops up correctly. However, The function inside WithGATracking component is not triggered anymore. The Reason for that I guess is because once the <Modal ... /> is returned, it stays there forever

Comment: You can debug that by loggin into the HOC and checking if its rendered or not, and it should if `this.props.isOpen` is true

Comment: I agree with you. But when a webpage is opened, initially all modals on this webpage have not been opened yet, so they are all closed, in other words, isOpen is always false, so the GAModal always return <Modal ... />, that's why the <GATrackingModal .../> is never called.   I think it's a code design fault. I will move the piece of code which controls showing or hiding the Modal outside GAModal component.  Thank you for your help :)